# How to place a panedWindow behind another panedWindow tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The title basically says it. Right now I have the two panedWindows attached to the root window. I would like the windows to either `lift()` or `lower()` one panedWindow on top of the other when a button is pressed rather than the panedWindows being stacked on top of each other in the same window.

I also understand there may be a better way of implementing this sort of menu feature. If you know a better way, that would be great too.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried using `grid` or `place` to stack them, and then call `lift()` or `lower()`?

Comment: @BryanOakley I just tried it and it worked. I set them both on the grid at  
row = 0. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `.grid(row = 0)` on both panedWindows. Then I called lift on the window I wanted to raise up and it worked.